# Does add new field to Solr with store true only require rebuilding of indexes?

Tags: indexing, solr

I want to add a new field to Solr schema but this field will not be indexed so do i need to re index everything or it is required only in case we add a new field with index true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the field populated for old documents (i.e. only new documents have this field), reindexing isn't necessary, even if the field would have been indexed.

If you're *changing* the (indexing) definition of a field (i.e. not adding a new field), reindexing is a necessity since you'd otherwise have different rules for how the stored tokens for that field were generated.

Removing fields from your schema isn't usually a problem either, but the field data will still remain in your index.